# How to retrieve a column based if another column matches the column in another dataframe?

Tags: r, tidyverse

If the `cmoic.kirp$clust.res$sampID` matches either the `cmoic.kirp.sub1.k4$sampID` OR `cmoic.kirp.sub2.k5$sampID`, I want to assign the corresponding `cmoic.kirp.sub1.k4$clust.res$clust` or `cmoic.kirp.sub1.k4$clust.res$clust` as `cmoic.kirp$clust.res$clust`

```
library(tidyverse)
cmoic.kirp$clust.res$clust <- cmoic.kirp %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(ID = cmoic.kirp$clust.res[samID %in% cmoic.kirp.sub1.k4 | samID %in% cmoic.kirp.sub2.k5]) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
cmoic.kirp$clust.res$clust
```

Traceback:

```
Error in UseMethod("rowwise") : 
  no applicable method for 'rowwise' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Data:

`cmoic.kirp$clust.res`

```
> dput(cmoic.kirp$clust.res)
structure(list(samID = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7288.01A", "TCGA.A4.7583.01A", "TCGA.A4.7584.01A", "TCGA.A4.7585.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7734.01A", "TCGA.A4.7915.01A", "TCGA.A4.7996.01A", "TCGA.A4.7997.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.8098.01A", "TCGA.A4.8311.01A", "TCGA.A4.8517.01A", "TCGA.A4.8630.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.A57E.01A", "TCGA.AL.7173.01A", "TCGA.AL.A5DJ.01A", "TCGA.B1.5398.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.7332.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47M.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47N.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47O.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.A654.01A", "TCGA.B1.A657.01A", "TCGA.B3.8121.01A", "TCGA.B3.A6W5.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.5155.01A", "TCGA.B9.5156.01A", "TCGA.B9.7268.01A", "TCGA.B9.A44B.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A5W7.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W8.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W9.01A", "TCGA.B9.A69E.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A8YH.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YI.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5875.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5877.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5878.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5879.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5880.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5881.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5882.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5883.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5885.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5887.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5888.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5889.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5890.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5891.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5892.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5893.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5894.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7044.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7046.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7048.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7049.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7050.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7051.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7053.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7055.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7056.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7058.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7060.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7061.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7062.01A", "TCGA.DW.5560.01A", "TCGA.DW.5561.01A", "TCGA.DW.7834.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7837.01A", "TCGA.DW.7838.01A", "TCGA.DW.7839.01A", "TCGA.DW.7840.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7841.01A", "TCGA.DW.7842.01A", "TCGA.DW.7963.01B", "TCGA.DZ.6131.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6132.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6133.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6134.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6135.01A", 
"TCGA.EV.5901.01A", "TCGA.EV.5902.01A", "TCGA.EV.5903.01A", "TCGA.F9.A4JJ.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A7Q0.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7VF.01A", "TCGA.F9.A8NY.01A", "TCGA.F9.A97G.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6789.01A", "TCGA.G7.6790.01A", "TCGA.G7.6792.01A", "TCGA.G7.6793.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6795.01A", "TCGA.G7.6796.01A", "TCGA.G7.6797.01A", "TCGA.G7.7501.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.7502.01A", "TCGA.G7.A4TM.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LB.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LC.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.A8LD.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LE.01A", "TCGA.GL.6846.01A", "TCGA.GL.7773.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.7966.01A", "TCGA.GL.8500.01A", "TCGA.GL.A4EM.01A", "TCGA.GL.A59R.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.A9DC.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DD.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DE.01A", "TCGA.HE.7128.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.7129.01A", "TCGA.HE.7130.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NF.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NH.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NI.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NJ.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NK.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NL.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A40U.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40X.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40Y.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83V.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A83W.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8195.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8196.01A", "TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A", 
"TCGA.J7.6720.01A", "TCGA.J7.8537.01A", "TCGA.J7.A8I2.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GD.01A", 
"TCGA.KV.A6GE.01A", "TCGA.KV.A74V.01A", "TCGA.MH.A55Z.01A", "TCGA.MH.A560.01A", 
"TCGA.MH.A562.01A", "TCGA.MH.A855.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E6.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E7.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5E8.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EA.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EB.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5ED.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.AAVL.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVM.01A", "TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A", "TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A", 
"TCGA.Q2.A5QZ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71R.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71U.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SM.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SN.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SP.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SQ.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SR.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SS.01A", "TCGA.UN.AAZ9.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PJ.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PK.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PL.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PN.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", "TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A"
), clust = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", 
"TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", "TCGA.A4.7583.01A", "TCGA.A4.7584.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7585.01A", "TCGA.A4.7734.01A", "TCGA.A4.7915.01A", "TCGA.A4.7996.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7997.01A", "TCGA.A4.8098.01A", "TCGA.A4.8311.01A", "TCGA.A4.8517.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.8630.01A", "TCGA.A4.A57E.01A", "TCGA.AL.7173.01A", "TCGA.AL.A5DJ.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.5398.01A", "TCGA.B1.7332.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47M.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47N.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.A47O.01A", "TCGA.B1.A654.01A", "TCGA.B1.A657.01A", "TCGA.B3.8121.01A", 
"TCGA.B3.A6W5.01A", "TCGA.B9.5155.01A", "TCGA.B9.5156.01A", "TCGA.B9.7268.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A44B.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W7.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W8.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W9.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A69E.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YH.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YI.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5875.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5877.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5878.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5879.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5880.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5881.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5882.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5883.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5885.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5887.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5888.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5889.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5890.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5891.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5892.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5893.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5894.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7044.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7046.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7048.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7049.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7050.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7051.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7053.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7055.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7056.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7058.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7060.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7061.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7062.01A", "TCGA.DW.5560.01A", "TCGA.DW.5561.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7834.01A", "TCGA.DW.7837.01A", "TCGA.DW.7838.01A", "TCGA.DW.7839.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7840.01A", "TCGA.DW.7841.01A", "TCGA.DW.7842.01A", "TCGA.DW.7963.01B", 
"TCGA.DZ.6131.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6132.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6133.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6134.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6135.01A", "TCGA.EV.5901.01A", "TCGA.EV.5902.01A", "TCGA.EV.5903.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A4JJ.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7Q0.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7VF.01A", "TCGA.F9.A8NY.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A97G.01A", "TCGA.G7.6789.01A", "TCGA.G7.6790.01A", "TCGA.G7.6792.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6793.01A", "TCGA.G7.6795.01A", "TCGA.G7.6796.01A", "TCGA.G7.6797.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.7501.01A", "TCGA.G7.7502.01A", "TCGA.G7.A4TM.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LB.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.A8LC.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LD.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LE.01A", "TCGA.GL.6846.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.7773.01A", "TCGA.GL.7966.01A", "TCGA.GL.8500.01A", "TCGA.GL.A4EM.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.A59R.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DC.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DD.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DE.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.7128.01A", "TCGA.HE.7129.01A", "TCGA.HE.7130.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NF.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NH.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NI.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NJ.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NK.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NL.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40U.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40X.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40Y.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A83V.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83W.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8195.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8196.01A", 
"TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A", "TCGA.J7.6720.01A", "TCGA.J7.8537.01A", "TCGA.J7.A8I2.01A", 
"TCGA.KV.A6GD.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GE.01A", "TCGA.KV.A74V.01A", "TCGA.MH.A55Z.01A", 
"TCGA.MH.A560.01A", "TCGA.MH.A562.01A", "TCGA.MH.A855.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E6.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5E7.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E8.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EA.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EB.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5ED.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVL.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVM.01A", "TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A", 
"TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A", "TCGA.Q2.A5QZ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71R.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71U.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SM.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SN.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SP.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SQ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SR.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SS.01A", "TCGA.UN.AAZ9.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PJ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PK.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PL.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PN.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", 
"TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A"))
```

`cmoic.kirp.sub1.k4$clust.res`

```
> dput(cmoic.kirp.sub1.k4$clust.res)
structure(list(samID = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7585.01A", "TCGA.A4.7915.01A", "TCGA.A4.8098.01A", "TCGA.A4.A57E.01A", 
"TCGA.AL.7173.01A", "TCGA.AL.A5DJ.01A", "TCGA.B1.5398.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47O.01A", 
"TCGA.B3.8121.01A", "TCGA.B9.5156.01A", "TCGA.B9.A44B.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W8.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A69E.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YI.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5875.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5877.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5878.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5879.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5880.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5881.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5882.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5883.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5885.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5887.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5888.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5889.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5890.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5891.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5892.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5893.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5894.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7044.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7046.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7048.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7049.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7050.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7053.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7055.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7056.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7058.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7060.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7061.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7062.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7838.01A", "TCGA.DW.7963.01B", "TCGA.DZ.6131.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6132.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6134.01A", "TCGA.F9.A4JJ.01A", "TCGA.F9.A8NY.01A", "TCGA.F9.A97G.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6789.01A", "TCGA.G7.6790.01A", "TCGA.G7.6792.01A", "TCGA.G7.6793.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6796.01A", "TCGA.G7.7501.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LD.01A", "TCGA.GL.7966.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.A4EM.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DD.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DE.01A", "TCGA.HE.7128.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.7130.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NF.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NK.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40U.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A40X.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40Y.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83V.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8195.01A", 
"TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A", "TCGA.J7.8537.01A", "TCGA.J7.A8I2.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GD.01A", 
"TCGA.MH.A560.01A", "TCGA.MH.A855.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E6.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E8.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5EA.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EB.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5ED.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVM.01A", 
"TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A", "TCGA.Q2.A5QZ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SM.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PN.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", "TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A"), clust = c("KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 4  ")), row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", 
"TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", "TCGA.A4.7585.01A", "TCGA.A4.7915.01A", "TCGA.A4.8098.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.A57E.01A", "TCGA.AL.7173.01A", "TCGA.AL.A5DJ.01A", "TCGA.B1.5398.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.A47O.01A", "TCGA.B3.8121.01A", "TCGA.B9.5156.01A", "TCGA.B9.A44B.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A5W8.01A", "TCGA.B9.A69E.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YI.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5875.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5877.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5878.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5879.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5880.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5881.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5882.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5883.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5885.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5887.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5888.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5889.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5890.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5891.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5892.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5893.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5894.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7044.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7046.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7048.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7049.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7050.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7053.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7055.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7056.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7058.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7060.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7061.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7062.01A", "TCGA.DW.7838.01A", "TCGA.DW.7963.01B", "TCGA.DZ.6131.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6132.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6134.01A", "TCGA.F9.A4JJ.01A", "TCGA.F9.A8NY.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A97G.01A", "TCGA.G7.6789.01A", "TCGA.G7.6790.01A", "TCGA.G7.6792.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6793.01A", "TCGA.G7.6796.01A", "TCGA.G7.7501.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LD.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.7966.01A", "TCGA.GL.A4EM.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DD.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DE.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.7128.01A", "TCGA.HE.7130.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NF.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NK.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A40U.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40X.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40Y.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83V.01A", 
"TCGA.IZ.8195.01A", "TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A", "TCGA.J7.8537.01A", "TCGA.J7.A8I2.01A", 
"TCGA.KV.A6GD.01A", "TCGA.MH.A560.01A", "TCGA.MH.A855.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E6.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5E8.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EA.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EB.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5ED.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.AAVM.01A", "TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A", "TCGA.Q2.A5QZ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SM.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PN.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", "TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A"), class = "data.frame")
```

`cmoic.kirp.sub2.k5$clust.res`

```
> dput(cmoic.kirp.sub2.k5$clust.res)
structure(list(samID = c("TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", "TCGA.A4.7583.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7584.01A", "TCGA.A4.7734.01A", "TCGA.A4.7996.01A", "TCGA.A4.7997.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.8311.01A", "TCGA.A4.8517.01A", "TCGA.A4.8630.01A", "TCGA.B1.7332.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.A47M.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47N.01A", "TCGA.B1.A654.01A", "TCGA.B1.A657.01A", 
"TCGA.B3.A6W5.01A", "TCGA.B9.5155.01A", "TCGA.B9.7268.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W7.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A5W9.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YH.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7051.01A", "TCGA.DW.5560.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.5561.01A", "TCGA.DW.7834.01A", "TCGA.DW.7837.01A", "TCGA.DW.7839.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7840.01A", "TCGA.DW.7841.01A", "TCGA.DW.7842.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6133.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6135.01A", "TCGA.EV.5901.01A", "TCGA.EV.5902.01A", "TCGA.EV.5903.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A7Q0.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7VF.01A", "TCGA.G7.6795.01A", "TCGA.G7.6797.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.7502.01A", "TCGA.G7.A4TM.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LB.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LC.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.A8LE.01A", "TCGA.GL.6846.01A", "TCGA.GL.7773.01A", "TCGA.GL.8500.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.A59R.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DC.01A", "TCGA.HE.7129.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NH.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NI.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NJ.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NL.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83W.01A", 
"TCGA.IZ.8196.01A", "TCGA.J7.6720.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GE.01A", "TCGA.KV.A74V.01A", 
"TCGA.MH.A55Z.01A", "TCGA.MH.A562.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E7.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVL.01A", 
"TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71R.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71U.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SN.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SQ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SR.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SS.01A", "TCGA.UN.AAZ9.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PJ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PK.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PL.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A"
), clust = c("KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 5  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 5  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 5  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 4  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 5  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  ", 
"KIRP Type 2 Subtype 5  ", "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  ")), row.names = c("TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7583.01A", "TCGA.A4.7584.01A", "TCGA.A4.7734.01A", "TCGA.A4.7996.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7997.01A", "TCGA.A4.8311.01A", "TCGA.A4.8517.01A", "TCGA.A4.8630.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.7332.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47M.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47N.01A", "TCGA.B1.A654.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.A657.01A", "TCGA.B3.A6W5.01A", "TCGA.B9.5155.01A", "TCGA.B9.7268.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A5W7.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W9.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YH.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7051.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.5560.01A", "TCGA.DW.5561.01A", "TCGA.DW.7834.01A", "TCGA.DW.7837.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7839.01A", "TCGA.DW.7840.01A", "TCGA.DW.7841.01A", "TCGA.DW.7842.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6133.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6135.01A", "TCGA.EV.5901.01A", "TCGA.EV.5902.01A", 
"TCGA.EV.5903.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7Q0.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7VF.01A", "TCGA.G7.6795.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6797.01A", "TCGA.G7.7502.01A", "TCGA.G7.A4TM.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LB.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.A8LC.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LE.01A", "TCGA.GL.6846.01A", "TCGA.GL.7773.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.8500.01A", "TCGA.GL.A59R.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DC.01A", "TCGA.HE.7129.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NH.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NI.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NJ.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NL.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A83W.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8196.01A", "TCGA.J7.6720.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GE.01A", 
"TCGA.KV.A74V.01A", "TCGA.MH.A55Z.01A", "TCGA.MH.A562.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E7.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.AAVL.01A", "TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71R.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71U.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SN.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SQ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SR.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SS.01A", 
"TCGA.UN.AAZ9.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PJ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PK.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PL.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
mget(ls(pattern = 'cmoic')) %>% reduce(left_join, by  = 'samID') %>% mutate(samID, ID = coalesce(clust.y, clust), clust = clust.x, .keep = "unused")
```

We could do a left join after binding df2 and df3:

the data frames are like in order cmoic1, cmoic2, cmoic3.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(cmoic1, 
          bind_rows(cmoic2, cmoic3), by = "samID")
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 202 × 3
   samID            clust.x clust.y                  
   <chr>              <dbl> <chr>                    
 1 TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A       1 "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  "
 2 TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A       2 "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  "
 3 TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A       2 "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  "
 4 TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A       1 "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  "
 5 TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A       2 "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 1  "
 6 TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A       2 "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 2  "
 7 TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A       1 "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 2  "
 8 TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A       2 "KIRP Type 2 Subtype 3  "
 9 TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A       1 "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 1  "
10 TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A       1 "KIRP Type 1 Subtype 3  "
# … with 192 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Or may be reduce with left_join if there are many datasets `mget(ls(pattern = 'cmoic')) %>% reduce(left_join, by  = 'samID') %>% mutate(samID, ID = coalesce(clust.y, clust), clust = clust.x, .keep = "unused") `